# Asterisk pyramid using php while loop

Tags: php

```
$i=0; $j=5; $k=0;

while($i < 5 ) {
    while($j > $i){
        echo " ";
        $j--;
    }
    while($k <= $i){
        echo '*';
        ++$k;
    }       

    echo "<br/>";
    $i++;
}
```

I am trying to creating asterisk pyramid using while loop with php, but the output as image enclosed. The asterisk character not show an pyramid. Instead of just single line:

[image: output from above code]

Please enlighten me the error of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<pre><?php

$left  = 4;
$right = 4;
$i = 0;

while($i < 5 ) {
     $j=0;
     while($j<11){
        if($j >= $left  &&  $j <= $right){
               echo "*";
         }else{
                 echo " ";
          }
        $j++;
    }

 echo "<br>";
 $left--;$right++;
 $i++;
```

}
?>

try this one, If you are interested to use only while loop, But try to understand the flow and learn and debug your issues

Answer (score 2):

You have to set $j=5 and $k=0 on each iteration of while ($i < 5).
Futhermore the web browser will convert your space characters ' ' to one space. So you need to use '`&nbsp;`' html character instead to see the result with more spaces.

```
$i=0; $j=5; $k=0;

while($i < 5 ) {
    $j=5; $k=0;

    while($j > $i){
        echo "&nbsp;";
        $j--;
    }
    while($k <= $i){
        echo '*';
        ++$k;

    }


    echo "<br/>";
    $i++;
}
```

Output screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqtEr.jpg